# Read file line by line and return all to a variable in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to read a file line by line and store the result in a variable, is that possible?

```
const fs = require('fs');

const allFileContents = fs.readFileSync('test.log', 'utf-8');
allFileContents.split(/\r?\n/).forEach(line =>  {
  console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
  return line; *<-- Returns undefined because it goes through all the lines of the file, but could everything be stored in a single variable to return the result?*
});
```

File example:

```
1 Word
2 Word
3 Word
```

Part of my complete code:

```
function readLogFile(){
        const allFileContents = fs.readFileSync('test.log', 'utf-8');
                allFileContents.split(/\r?\n/).forEach(line =>  {
                return line;
        });
}

var file = await readLogFile();
console.log(file); //Response: Undefined
sendEmailNotification(jobname, status, email, file)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused with what you're trying to do. In your example: `allFileContents` will already be the entire contents in an array.

Comment: I added part of the code to the question, I want to get the value returned by `readLogFile()` to use it in another function, but the answer is `undifined`

Comment: I think if you just `return allFileContents;` from  the `readLogFile` function it should do exactly what you want. I also don't think you need to `await` the results. Give it a shot and let me know!

Comment: Now yes, it worked, thanks